# Modifying JSON in Groovy (or JOLT)

Tags: json, groovy, jolt

I've a simple JSON look like:

```
{
  "account_login" : "google@gmail.com",
  "view_id" : 1868715,
  "join_id" : "utm_campaign=toyota&utm_content=multiformat_sites&utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=facebook",
  "start_date" : "2020-02-03",
  "end_date" : "2020-08-30"
}
```

With following Groovy script ([from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65459944/14628464)):

```
def content = """
{
  "account_login" : "google@gmail.com",
  "view_id" : 1868715,
  "join_id" : "utm_campaign=toyota&utm_content=multiformat_sites&utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=facebook",
  "start_date" : "2020-02-03",
  "end_date" : "2020-08-30"
}
"""

def slurped = new JsonSlurper().parseText(content)
 
def builder = new JsonBuilder(slurped)

builder.content.join_id = builder.content.join_id.split("\\s*&\\s*")  //# to array
        .collectEntries{ 
                //# convert each item to map entry
                String[] utmMarks = it.trim().split("\\s*=\\s*")
                utmMarks[0] = [
                    "utm_medium"   : "ga:medium",
                    "utm_campaign" : "ga:campaign",
                    "utm_source"   : "ga:source",
                    "utm_content"  : "ga:adContent",
                    "utm_term"     : "ga:keyword",
                ].get( utmMarks[0] )
                utmMarks
            }
        .findAll{ 
             k,v-> k && v!=null  //# filter out empty/null keys
        } 
//builder.content.filters = ...
println(builder.toPrettyString())
```

I'll get:

```
{
    "account_login": "google@gmail.com",
    "view_id": 1868715,
    "join_id": {
        "ga:campaign": "toyota",
        "ga:adContent": "multiformat_sites",
        "ga:medium": "cpc",
        "ga:source": "facebook"
    },
    "start_date": "2020-02-03",
    "end_date": "2020-08-30"
}
```

I want to update this script (or write new) and add new property: array `filters` to modified json above. Expected output:

```
{
   "account_login":"google@gmail.com",
   "view_id":1868715,
   "join_id":{
      "ga:campaign":"toyota",
      "ga:adContent":"multiformat_sites",
      "ga:medium":"cpc",
      "ga:source":"facebook"
   },
   "start_date":"2020-02-03",
   "end_date":"2020-08-30",
   "converted_utm_marks":"ga:campaign=toyota&ga:adContent=multiformat_sites&ga:medium=cpc&ga:source=facebook",
   "filters":[
      {
         "dimensionName":"ga:medium",
         "operator":"EXACT",
         "expressions":[
            "cpc"
         ]
      },
      {
         "dimensionName":"ga:adContent",
         "operator":"EXACT",
         "expressions":[
            "multiformat_sites"
         ]
      },
      {
         "dimensionName":"ga:campaign",
         "operator":"EXACT",
         "expressions":[
            "toyota"
         ]
      },
      {
         "dimensionName":"ga:source",
         "operator":"EXACT",
         "expressions":[
            "facebook"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

But the problem is that the set of filters for each JSON will be different. This set depends directly on the `join_id` set. If JSON `join_id` will contain:

```
"join_id": {
        "ga:campaign": "toyota",
        "ga:keyword": "car"
    }
```

`filters` array should be:

```
[
      {
         "dimensionName":"ga:campaign",
         "operator":"EXACT",
         "expressions":[
            "toyota"
         ]
      },
      {
         "dimensionName":"ga:keyword",
         "operator":"EXACT",
         "expressions":[
            "car"
         ]
      }
]
```

`operator` is always equals `EXACT`. Property `dimensionName` - is a `join_id.propety` name. `Expressions` is a `join_id.property` value. So, property `filters` based on `join_id` and I need to loop through `join_id` property and build `filters` array with described structure. How to achieve expected output? **JOLT** configuration appreciated also.

I can't even simple iterate through `join_id` map:

```
slurped.join_id.each { println "Key: $it.key = Value: $it.value" }
```

I got the error:

```
/home/jdoodle.groovy: 24: illegal colon after argument expression;
   solution: a complex label expression before a colon must be parenthesized @ line 24, column 28.
             .collect { [it.ga:campaign] }
```

**UPDATE**

I found out how to build this array:

```
def array = 
[ 
    filters: slurped.join_id.collect {key, value ->
            [
                dimensionName: key,
                operator: "EXACT",
                expressions: [
                    value
                    ]
            ]
        } 
]
```

Seems like i got it:

```
def slurped = new JsonSlurper().parseText(content)
def builder = new JsonBuilder(slurped)

builder.content.filters = builder.content.join_id.collect {key, value ->
            [
                dimensionName: key,
                operator: "EXACT",
                expressions: [
                    value
                    ]
            ]
        }
```

Are there any better solutions?

Comment: the line in the error message is not in your code.  that error message there should be fixed by something like `["it.ga": "campaign"]` - yet it's unclear, if you want to replace from it and a map or just some list.  So it could as well be `[it."ga:campaign"]`

Comment: Yeap, this is my bad. I tested something and forgot to remove invalid value.

Comment: Better by what definition? Collect is the way to do. Whether the JsonBuilder here is worse than let's say JsonOuput you have to measure yourself, to your metric of "better".

Comment: Extra code/code smell/perfomance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def slurped = new JsonSlurper().parseText(content)
def builder = new JsonBuilder(slurped)

builder.content.filters = builder.content.join_id.collect {key, value ->
            [
                dimensionName: key,
                operator: "EXACT",
                expressions: [
                    value
                    ]
            ]
        }
```